# How to speed up neo4j bloom SEARCH PHRASE?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to show on the graph all connections (max.6) from the specific node (Company).

I simply used the below:

```
MATCH path=(c:Company)-[*1..6]-()
where c.property1=$company
RETURN path, c
```

but it takes lot of time to execute the query.

Any suggestion how to modify this query or how to speed up the process?

Best regards!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, traversing 6 hops can be a lot especially in a well-connected graph.

However, I would suggest you use the following query to optimize your search:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((c:Company)-[*1..6]-(e))
where c.property1=$company AND NOT c = e
RETURN path, c
```